# How to handle a web server response with jquery to run a callback function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, httpresponse, jquery-callback

Is there any way to know when a web server response is sent to the client, in a traditional postback, so that I can execute a jQuery function?

For example, to put a `div` with a message or a simple alert saying "Succeed" without using the

```
Page.RegisterStartUpScript("<script type="text/javasctip">alert('Succeed')</script>);
```

nor

```
var request = $.ajax({
   url: "page/someWebMethod",
   type: "POST",
   data: {id : menuId},
   dataType: "html"
 });

 request.done(function(msg) {
    $('DivOk').show();
 });
```

Comment: Use the callback in Ajax to execute other jQuery functions.

Comment: I dont' use assyncronous approach.

Comment: BTW I'd like to know whether this is either a good question or not because I got 2 down votes.

Comment: In the sense that you're not asking about a specific issue with a code example, yes - this might be considered a bad question by some.

Comment: But I believe that there are a lot of questions in SO asking for arquitecth or theorical thinks that are very up voted.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the reader of the post and what they think is a valid SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without a specific application, however, remaining within jQuery methods, you could use the ansync: false option for jQuery's ajax method and make a synchronous as demonstrated on the answer here: [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the HTTP method used (assuming you've done a POST for example), then do something, for example in your ASPX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var has_posted = <%= GetPosted() %>;

    if (has_posted) callSomething();

</script>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected string GetPosted()
{
    return (Request.HttpMethod == "POST").ToString().ToLower();
}
```

I usually do this using `<form>` however so can pass in extra checks using hidden `<input>` fields, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: (a none traditional way) :)

shouldn't [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)'s success give you what you want?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: He's talking about a postback, which wouldn't be async.

Comment: yep, he did say in a traditional way... missed that part.